# How to get the route its structure in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Let's say I have the following route in Laravel:

```
Route::get('posts/{post}/comments/{comment}', function ($postId, $commentId) {
    //
});
```

And let's say I'm on the following url: `posts/3/comments/54`

I can get the url as a string by accessing the `url()` method, this would give me back the exact url.

In my case, I need something else. Is there a way to get the route's structure? I want to do something like this:

`if(someUrlStructureFunction() == "posts/{post}/comments/{comment}") //do something`

Thanks!

Comment: what are you trying to achieve by checking the url structure?

Comment: Each user has certain roles. Each request (so the url + the request type) has individual rules on which users with which roles are able to access it. So for example, the given url and a POST request can only be accessed by let's say admins. But maybe the url and GET request can be done by anyone for example. These things are all saved in a DB. We rather not use the controller's action name to identify this because this is easier to be accidentally changed in the code without changing it in the DB

Comment: I think you can accomplish that with Middleware, where you filter the requests by each user role. Learn more: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/middleware

Comment: @Derp Tying that to the route/URL seems odd. You should be using stuff like https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authorization#via-controller-helpers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using resources, the actions have names by default, so your post comments could be:

```
Route::resource('posts.comments', 'PostsCommentsController');

php artisan route:list
+--------+-----------+----------------------------------------+------------------------+------------------------------------------------------+------------+
| Domain | Method    | URI                                    | Name                   | Action                                               | Middleware |
+--------+-----------+----------------------------------------+------------------------+------------------------------------------------------+------------+
|        | GET|HEAD  | posts/{posts}/comments                 | posts.comments.index   | App\Http\Controllers\PostsCommentsController@index   |            |
|        | POST      | posts/{posts}/comments                 | posts.comments.store   | App\Http\Controllers\PostsCommentsController@store   |            |
|        | GET|HEAD  | posts/{posts}/comments/create          | posts.comments.create  | App\Http\Controllers\PostsCommentsController@create  |            |
|        | GET|HEAD  | posts/{posts}/comments/{comments}      | posts.comments.show    | App\Http\Controllers\PostsCommentsController@show    |            |
|        | PUT|PATCH | posts/{posts}/comments/{comments}      | posts.comments.update  | App\Http\Controllers\PostsCommentsController@update  |            |
|        | DELETE    | posts/{posts}/comments/{comments}      | posts.comments.destroy | App\Http\Controllers\PostsCommentsController@destroy |            |
|        | GET|HEAD  | posts/{posts}/comments/{comments}/edit | posts.comments.edit    | App\Http\Controllers\PostsCommentsController@edit    |            |
+--------+-----------+----------------------------------------+------------------------+------------------------------------------------------+------------+
```

Then you could use `Request::route()->getName()` to analyze which one was called.

Comment: I guess that'll do the job too! Still funny that Laravel doesn't have something to get the route signature, I guess there sometimes might be a reason where that is actually necessary.

Answer (score 3):

Give your route [a name](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#named-routes):

```
Route::get('user/profile', 'UserController@showProfile')->name('profile');
```

<sup>(That's the Laravel 5.3 syntax. It's slightly different in earlier versions.)</sup>

then, you can use:

```
Request::route()->getName()
```

to check if you're on that route.

Comment: Thought about that option indeed. Problem would be that we have to give 200+ routes a name, but I guess there aren't many other options.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comment you want to restrict certain routes to specific roles

you can try using route groups then create a middleware for each roles: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#route-groups

```
//put your admin routes inside this
Route::group(['middleware' => 'admins'], function () {
    Route::get('posts/{post}/comments/{comment}', function ($postId, $commentId) {
        //
    });
});

//put your users routes inside this
Route::group(['middleware' => 'users'], function () {
    Route::get('posts/{post}/comments/{comment}', function ($postId, $commentId) {
            //
    });
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work with Resource routes though, which we are using a lot. Sometimes the Show method is allowed to be seen while the create method isn't

Comment: so each methods in the controller has different roles too?

Comment: Yup. For example, everybody can see posts but not everybody can create one. This is defined with roles in the system.

Comment: Nope, just a table in the database with roles and users with the roles connected to them. But I think @ceejayoz his comment is actually pretty neat and exactly what I'm looking for.